# Nontrivial expansion in sumsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}/p$, let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and let $B:=\{f(a): a \in A\}$.

Can we conclude that $|A+B|$ is large if $f$ is a sufficiently "nice" function?  For instance say that $f(a)=a^2$.  Then can we say that if $|A|=1000\sqrt{p}$ or even if $|A|=\frac{p}{\log^{*}(p)}$, then $|A+B| \ge p/100$?

The idea should be that $A+B$ is only small if $A,B$ are related by some additive structure, and if $f$ is a sufficiently random function then it should kill any structure so that $A+B$ should be large.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a partial "yes", to complement Sam Zbarsky's negative answer to the question.

There are a bunch of different papers on this topic focusing on different functions $f$ and in different ranges. To simplify things, I will focus on $f(x)=x^2$, since you mentioned it.

For $|A|< p^{5/8}$, a result of Pham, Vinh and de Zeeuw gives $|A+f(A)| \gg |A|^{6/5}$.

For larger sets, I cannot find a reference from the top of my head, but I am quite confident that exponential sum techniques could prove that
\begin{equation} \label{claim}
|A+f(A)| \gg \min \left \{ \sqrt{p|A|}, \frac{|A|^2}{\sqrt{p}} \right \}.
\end{equation}
See for example Theorem 7 in [this paper](https://www.math.waikato.ac.nz/~kab/papers/MultiplSumProd7.pdf) of Balog, Broughan and Shparlinksi, which implies this result for $f(x)=x^{-1}$. I am pretty sure that I have seen this result with $f(x)=x^2$ in the literature at some point, but cannot remember where right now. If this claim is correct then it is optimal, as you can construct a set $A$ of any given size with $|A+A^2| \ll \sqrt{|A|p}$.

Answer (score 4):

We can't. This is written for $f(a)=a^2$ but it should work for any "sufficiently random" function, in fact it uses "randomness".

Let
$$
A=\left\{a\in \left[1,\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log^*p}}\right]\,\Bigg\vert\, f(a)\in \left[1,\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log^*p}}\right]\right\}
$$

Then it's not hard to see that $|A|\ge \frac{p}{10\log^*p}$ (essentially using the fact that squares on intervals $[a,a+\lfloor p/2a\rfloor]$ are approximately uniformly distributed, and looking at $a<\frac{p}{3\sqrt{\log^* p}}$. However,
$$
|A+A|\le\left|\left[1,\frac{2p}{\sqrt{\log^*p}}\right]\right|=\frac{2p}{\sqrt{\log^*p}}
$$

Edited to add: I think this should work for any function $f$ by introducing random offsets to the two intervals; that is we'll get some set $A$ so that both $A$ and $f(A)$ fit in an interval of size $\frac{p}{\sqrt{\log^*p}}$, but $\mathbb E|A|\ge \frac{p}{10\log^*p}$. Thus, some choice of offsets gives a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a bit more on why $|A| \ge p/10\log^*p$?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal divide the interval $[p^{2/3},p/(3\log^*p)]$ into intervals of the form $[a,a+\lfloor p/(2a)\rfloor]$, with about $\log^*p$ numbers left over. The elements of each interval are sent to a sequence whose successive differences are $(2+o(1))a$ and which has $\lfloor p/(2a)\rfloor+1$ elements. Thus at least $\frac{p}{4a\sqrt{\log^*p}}$ of them lie in the interval $[1,p/\sqrt{\log^* p}]$, which makes a fraction of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\log^*p}}$. Summing over all such intervals, we get the desired result (and the constant 10 has a safety margin).

Comment: What is meant by $\log^*p$, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Comment: In case anyone else is curious, it's "the number of times the logarithm function must be iteratively applied before the result is less than or equal to $1$."

Comment: I just chose it because it is a function that grows to infinity very slowly, so that $|A|=o(p)$ but $A$ would still be pretty large.